# Why '+' act like a parse in javascript when converting from string to float or integer and how it differs regarding on performance?

Tags: javascript, parsing

`parseFloat("10.1") + parseFloat("32.3")`

vs

`+ "10.1" + + "32.3"`

both statement will produce the same result 42.4

using this statement:

`+ "10.1" + + "32.3"`

Why does `+` act like a parse and how each statement affects the performance in the program?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus

Comment: I'm having a difficult time framing an answer to the "why" part of this question. The unary `+` operator converts string input into numeric output because that's what it's specified to do. Maybe something closer to what you're looking for is "unary `+` is like unary `-` in that both always yield a number value, but unary `+` doesn't negate its operand" perhaps?

Comment: It seems like you have two questions here: "why" and "how fast". Maybe post a different question concerning performance?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript uses implicit conversions. The unary `+` only accepts numbers, so, when you give it a string, it converts it into a number. JavaScript does this by parsing the string as a number. Since JavaScript doesn't have an integer type, it is always parsed as a floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the performance question: [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/unary-operator-vs-parse-float).

From my tests, the unary operator `+` is 8 times faster than parseFloat.

I'd guess this has to do with the expense of function calls in JS, etc.